# fsarchiver error

Tags: linux, selinux, fsarchiver

I'm running the following [fsarchiver](http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/Software/535640/fsarchiver.html) command:

```
$ fsarchiver restfs /tmp/backup/c0d0p2.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/cciss/c0d0p2
```

I get the following error:

```
[errno=22, Invalid argument]: oper_restore.c#213,extractar_restore_attr_xattr(): xattr:lsetxattr(/racoon,security.selinux) failed Statistics for filesystem 0
```

What is errno 22? How do I fix it? I'm using Red Hat 5.4, Linux kernel 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE

Comment: Again: please link your SU question and your question here, so people who read the question on one site can also find answers on the other site.

Comment: What operating system did you create the backup on? Did it use SELinux? Does your current system have SELinux enabled?

Comment: VTC: I do not believe there are enough details here to be possible to provide a reasonable answer. (Is SELinux enabled, and are there relevant AVC denial messages)